# Parameter distribution from profile likelihood

Tags: confidence-interval, modeling, chi-squared-test, profile-likelihood

This question is regarding profile likelihood to obtain CI of parameters. There is a published parameter values that best fits (using minimum chi square)the data for some mathematical model say y=f(theta,x,beta) where theta is my parameter of interest, x is the observable and beta is the nuisance parameter. The parameter distribution is given as distribution of theta with the value of chi square. They have marked one and two SD parameter bounds too. Is there a way I can infer on the parameter distribution? Are they normally or log normally distributed? My aim is to calculate the model uncertainties by simulation using the parameter distribution.

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You state that the "parameter distribution is given as distribution of theta" & then ask if there is "a way [you] can infer on the parameter distribution". Can you make your question clearer & more concrete? (Maybe you could include a concrete example.)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The publication gives a figure where the chi square (y axis) is plotted against the parameter (x axis) and minimum chi square is taken the parameter for the best fit along with one and two SD bounds. So in principle, I can get the mean parameter and SD from the figure. But I am not sure what is the underlying distribution of the parameters. Hope now it is clear.

Comment: What publication? Can you cite it (in your question)? Can you copy the text &/or figures that are confusing?

Comment: Bootstrapping could provide the sampling distribution of the parameter estimate.  I doubt you can conclude much from the profiles.  Note that it probably isn't correct to call it a profile *likelihood*, if the estimation procedure is based on a minimum chi-square procedure, unless maximizing the likelihood actually does correspond to minimizing a Mahalanobis distance (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance).

Comment: @AndrewM, I am not sure how bootstrapping is done on this. As I know only the parameter at which the minimum chi-square is obtained and the standard deviation of the parameter, I need to assume a known or standard distribution of parameters even to do bootstrapping, right?